Remove data key from firebase cloud message
I am implementing push notifications for React Native applications - both iOS and Android.
Currently I am running into a problem that firebase admin SDK in Java(my backend), always sends the data key even when I want to trigger a notification only payload. Sending like a mixed message prevents the background handler from triggering and makes it so the OS shows the notification but then it registers again when I open the app and thus it's displayed twice. This only happens in minimized state.
This is my backend code:
public static List<Boolean> sendPushNotificationToUsers(String title, String message, Collection<UserDevice> devices) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
        
        AndroidConfig androidConfig = AndroidConfig.builder()
                .setTtl(30000)
                //.putData(title, message)
                .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder().setIcon("ic_large_notification_icon").build())
                .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH).build();
        
        ApnsConfig apnsConfig = ApnsConfig.builder()
//              .putHeader("apns-topic", "com.nutrisoft.mobilenutri")
//              .putHeader("apns-priority", "5")
//              .putHeader("apns-push-type", "background")
                .setAps(Aps.builder().setContentAvailable(true).build())
                .build();
        
        Notification notification = Notification.builder().setTitle(title).setBody(message).build();
        
        MulticastMessage msg = MulticastMessage.builder()
                  .addAllTokens(devices.stream().map(userDevice -> userDevice.getDeviceToken()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
//                .putData("title", title)
//                .putData("message", message)
                  .setAndroidConfig(androidConfig)
                  .setApnsConfig(apnsConfig)
                  .setNotification(notification)
                  .build();
        

        BatchResponse response = FirebaseService.fcm.sendMulticast(msg);
        
        List<Boolean> ids = response.getResponses()
          .stream()
          .map(r -> r.isSuccessful())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(ids);
        
        return ids;
    }

This results in a payload like this received in onMessageReceived and not in the background handler:

{"contentAvailable": true, "data": {}, "from": "688859109590", "messageId": "1719432193006523", "notification": {"body": "Test", "title": "Obavijest"}}

How can I send it without the data key at all?
